# Acrescentar texto em um array e imprimindo com json_enconde do PHP

Tags: php

Tenho esse código em php que imprimi o  array do resultado do select mysql:

Ele no momento imprimi o nome, data e hora final e início do evento.

Como eu faria para acrescentar um item no array, como por exemplo, o "id" de cada registro?

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $start = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_GET["start"]);
        $end = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_GET["end"]);

        $result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT `id`, `start` ,`end` ,`title`,`ativo` FROM  `events` where (date(start) >= '$start' AND date(start) <= '$end' AND ativo='nao'  ) ");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {

            $events[] = $row; 
        }


        echo json_encode($events); 



        exit;
```

Comment: Nesse exemplo, parece que já esta retornando a linha completa dentro do array (com todos os valores definidos no select do sql). Como exatamente está sendo mostrado o resultado?

Answer (score 0):

Tenta dessa forma, assim você escolhe o que e a ordem que quer que apareça. Aconselho a começar a usar PDO

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$start = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_GET["start"]);
$end = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_GET["end"]);

$result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT `id`, `start` ,`end` ,`title`,`ativo` FROM  `events` where (date(start) >= '$start' AND date(start) <= '$end' AND ativo='nao'  ) ");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{           
    $events[] = array(
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'start' => $row['start'],
        'end' => $row['end']
    );
}
```

Comment: nao aparece nada desse modo que você disse, muito estranho